# Second Container registry in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry

I have an existing terraform script where one container registry is defined. We are in the process of creating a new one with customer managed key and once its established, the old one will be deleted.
So in the terraform script I copied the same module for container registry and gave a new name. But it gave an error saying multiple entries are seen. Then I gave count=2 in container registry module. That also gave an error.

I am unable to implement customer managed key as well due to this error.
Is there a way to achieve two container registry in one terraform script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Initially i tried to reproduce the same and tried to change the name
> of the registry , then new one got created deleting the old registry
> .It was fine.

- So then I jus copied the same module next to previous one and changed
  the name of reference only, without changing the registry name.Then
  it threw error as , it already exists.

> Note:make sure you save changes every time you modify and then do
> terraform flow.

I even got error as containerregistry1 already exists even if acr01 is changed to acr03 .(as registry name is not changed here)
[image]
But when I changed registry name also.then I could successfully create other similar instances of the registry successfully.

Even tried using **`count=3`** in container registry module which gave me the similar error.

```
provider "azurerm" {

  features {}

}


data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "<myResourcegroup>"
  
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {

  count = 3
  name                = "containerkavyasarabojuRegistry01"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Premium"
  admin_enabled       = false

  georeplications {
    location                = "East US"
    zone_redundancy_enabled = true
    tags                    = {}
  }

  ...
   ...
```

[image]

This is caused as the ***registry name must be unique*** too.***`Azure container registry has global scope`***( [resources having global scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/resource-naming#example-names-storage)).***`So it must be unique globally`***.

- So we must make sure registry name must be unique.

***So along with count = x, even registry name must be varied or incremented like below:***

> count = 3
> name                =
> "containerkavyasarabojuRegistry01${format("%03d", count.index + 1)}"

***example:***

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "<myresourcegroup>"
  
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  count = 3
  name                = "containerkavyasarabojuRegistry01${format("%03d", count.index + 1)}" //check this
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Premium"
  admin_enabled       = false
      
   ...
  georeplications {
    ...
  }

  ...
```

[image]

***RESULT:*** we can see the registries created with unique names.

[image]

You can check if acr name already exists through az cli -[***az acr check name***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-check-name-examples) before actually starting to give a name:

```
az acr check-name -n doesthisnameexist
```

**Reference**: [terraform-modules-and-multiple-instances](https://www.clounce.com/cloud/azure/terraform-modules-and-multiple-instances)